# ActiveRecord configuration for reading from slave MySQL box

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a very straight forward master/slave replication setup with MySQL. ActiveRecord is configured to hit the master hostname as would be expected in database.yml. My question is, is it currently possible to set an option for ActiveRecord to do all reads from a slave and leave writes to the master? I'm using Ruby on Rails/ActiveRecord 3.1.3. I haven't found any options to perform the following, just a single host entry field in database.yml. Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible, but you need to use a gem for it; it's not built into Rails itself.

I use [seamless database pool](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool) currently and it works great. [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) is another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [makara gem](https://github.com/taskrabbit/makara). It sends all `SELECT` statements to slaves and write operations to master.

Add this like to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'makara'
```

And then configure your database.ml like this:

```
production:
  adapter: 'mysql2_makara'
  database: 'MyAppProduction'
  # any other standard AR configurations

  # add a makara subconfig
  makara:

    # the following are default values
    blacklist_duration: 5
    master_ttl: 5
    sticky: true

    # list your connections with the override values (they're merged into the top-level config)
    # be sure to provide the role if master, role is assumed to be a slave if not provided
    connections:
      - role: master
        host: master.sql.host
      - role: slave
        host: slave1.sql.host
      - role: slave
        host: slave2.sql.host
```

Comment: I tried using Makara, however is there any way where I can make the default reads to be from master and only certain queries to be from slave? Octopus allows that using the ":using" clause.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Check this link : https://github.com/ankane/shorts/blob/master/Scaling-Reads.md

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same requirement. Currently, this is not possible in ActiveRecord.

We spiked out 2 gems, Octopus and Makara. I have written a blog comparing these 2 gems : https://ypoonawala.wordpress.com/2015/11/15/octopus-vs-makara-read-write-adapters-for-activerecord-2/

In my opinion, Makara works well and makes up for the issues with Octopus.